# Difference between char in Java and C# (particular problem with (char)-1)

Tags: c#, java

```
char x = (char)-1;
```

is valid in Java, but shows me the error (*Overflow in constant value computation*)

Should I use a different datatype in C#?

Comment: Which char do you expect -1 to represent?

Comment: It apparently represents an error-value

Comment: @BeamMe - I understand that is what is does, but what did you expect it to represent given that you where surprised by this?

Comment: I'm trying my best to port a java class to c#, I have not written the Java code and some things are a bit weird ;) So I don't know exactly why it's using -1 and what it represents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error occurs because C# is smarter about literals ("constant computation"). In C# one *could* do...

```
int x = -1;
char c = (char)x;
int y = c;
// y is 0xffff, as per Java
```

However, do note that 0xFFFF is an *invalid Unicode character* :)

Happy coding.

---

Using `unchecked` will also "work":

```
unchecked {
  char x = (char)-1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [definition of the C# `char` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9h8tsay%28v=vs.71%29.aspx); it's a 16-bit Unicode character, [same as in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).  If you are just looking for a 16-byte signed value, [then you might want a `short`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ybs77ex4%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

For your reference, [here is a list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exx3b86w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) of the integral types available to you in C#.

You can also use [an `unchecked` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74b4xzyw.aspx) such as `unchecked { char x = (char)-1; }`; however, if it were me and I was, for instance, using `-1` to represent an error value or some other marker, I would probably just use: `char x = (char)0xFFFF;` which gives you the same result, and a way of checking for an invalid value, without needing to circumvent the type check.